# Want to run a loop in existing python code

Tags: python, api

I am running a python program to fetch weather data from DarkSky weather website using API.
As of now I am fetching data for one location at a time by giving it's latitude and longitude.

What I want is... I want to give 2-4 location at a time and my code should fetch data for all those `Location(latitude, longitude)` which I have mentioned in my code

```
import os
import warnings
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from darksky import forecast
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm

def ping_darksky(time, key):

    WeatherData = forecast(key, *Location, time=day.isoformat())

    fetch = {
        'day': time,
        'windSpeed': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windSpeed', np.nan),
        'windGust': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windGust', np.nan),
        'windBearing': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windBearing', np.nan)}
    return fetch

def switch_key():


    with open("secret_key.txt", 'r') as key_file:
        api_keys = key_file.read().splitlines()

    for api_key in api_keys:
        yield api_key

#38.9072, 77.0369(DC)
#40.3029, 74.7337(Mercer)
#39.1547, 77.2405(Montgomery)
#40.1461, 82.4753(Licking)

# Define location(Lat & Long).
Location = (40.1461, -82.4753)
# Set up dataframe and path to which it will be saved.
COLUMNS = ["day", "windSpeed", "windGust"]
WEATHER_Location = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUMNS)
DATAOUT = os.path.join("data", "weather_WeatherData_daily.csv")
# Define start variables for the loop.

##YYYY, MM,DD
START = datetime(2018,1,27)
KEYGEN = switch_key()
KEY = next(KEYGEN)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Start data collection.")
    for day in tqdm(pd.date_range(START, periods=190)):
        try:
            row = ping_darksky(key=KEY, time=day)
            WEATHER_Location = WEATHER_Location.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        # If the server refuses to connect, change the key.
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
            try:
                KEY = next(KEYGEN)
                row = ping_darksky(key=KEY, time=day)
                WEATHER_Location = WEATHER_Location.append(row, ignore_index=True)
                continue
        # If there are no keys left, break the loop prematurely.
            except StopIteration:
                warnings.warn(
                    "End of keys reached. Your dataset might be incomplete.")
                break
        # Save data in each iteration.
        # This way you should end up with something at least.
        finally:
            WEATHER_Location.to_csv(DATAOUT)

    print("Wrote {} rows".format(WEATHER_Location.shape[0]))
```

Comment: What problem are you facing on running this code?

Comment: This code is working fine, but as I mentioned that I can fetch data for 1 location at a time. Just wanted to run a loop(by creating a list of Lat and Long for multiple  location) so that in one shot I can download data for multiple location

Comment: please refer this part:# Define location(Lat & Long).
Location = (40.1461, -82.4753)

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Hi Yash, I am getting data for fisr location only.. Hope I understood your sollution correctly(as I am new to Python)

Comment: locations = [[40.1461, -82.4753],[123, 213]]

def ping_darksky(time, key):

    for location in locations:
      WeatherData = forecast(key, *location, time=day.isoformat())
      fetch = {
        'day': time,
        'windSpeed': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windSpeed', np.nan),
        'windGust': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windGust', np.nan),
        'windBearing': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windBearing', np.nan)}
      return fetch

Comment: remove the * and try

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create a list of the locations
2. Create a dictionary

and call the relevant function by using values inside it.
Using list:

```
#locations = [[40.1461, -82.4753],[123, 213],........]
locations = [[40.1461, -82.4753],[123, 213]]

def ping_darksky(time, key):

    for location in locations:
      WeatherData = forecast(key, location, time=day.isoformat())
      fetch = {
        'day': time,
        'windSpeed': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windSpeed', np.nan),
        'windGust': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windGust', np.nan),
        'windBearing': WeatherData["daily"]["data"][0].get('windBearing', np.nan

        #here add up the data and finally return
        print(fetch)
```

Using dictionary:

```
locations = {40.1461: -82.4753, 123: 213}
for key,value in dicta.items():
      WeatherData = forecast(key, *[key, value], time=day.isoformat())
```

However, if the forecast function expects a list, it's better to go for list.

Comment: Only pulling data for first mentioned location only:-(

Comment: My bad, actually I was returning inside the loop so it will run only once, you can just print to check the output, I've updated my answer.

Comment: For List method, I am getting error as:                                                forecast() missing 1 required positional argument: 'longitude'

Comment: For Dictionary method: NameError: name 'dicta' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I would store the locations in a dictionary (AKA a hashmap) of tuples and loop over the keys

```
locations = {"DC":(38.9072, 77.0369), "Mercer":(40.3029, 74.7337), "Montgomery":(39.1547, 77.2405), "Licking":(40.1461, 82.4753)}
for key in locations.keys():
       location = locations[key]
       <YOUR MAIN CODE>
```

I would use a dictionary so that you could select a location by name in the future if you desired